# esdiff package for easily writing derivatives cannot handle subscripts properly?

Tags: math-mode, errors, subscripts

Here's a MnWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}
    $\diffp{V}{c_i}$
\end{document}
```

The error being returned:

```
line 14: Missing { inserted. $\diffp{V}{c_i}
```

From the log:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.14     $\diffp{V}{c_i}
                        $
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
```

The following causes the same error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}
    $\diffp{V}{c_{i}}$
\end{document}
```

How can I get `esdiff` to properly work with subscripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an extra pair of braces for the argument with scripts:

```
    $\diffp{V}{{c_{i}}}$
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\begin{document}
    $\diffp{V}{{c_{i}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The extra pair of braces forms a group thus `c_{i}` is seen as a "unit"; without it, TeX sees `c` as a first token, internally `\partial c` is built, and then ot takes `_` as the next token to form `\partial _`, which triggers the error.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @user89 The extra pair of braces forms a group thus `c_{i}` is seen as a "unit"; without it, TeX sees `c` as a first token and then `_` as the next token, producing the error.

Answer (score 9):

Not a serious answer but just for your information, there is `physics` package providing this and many other goodies. For details, refer to its documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
    \[\pdv{V}{c_{i}} \quad 
      \pderivative{x} \quad 
      \pdv{x} \quad 
      \pdv[n]{f}{x} \quad 
      \pdv{f}{x}{y} \quad 
      \pdv{x}(X) \quad
      \pdv*{f}{x}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow -- cool! I'll check this out. Thanks so much.